# Need help in cryptography, C programming

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography

I have developed a sample code that does AES-256 Encryption. It takes a key, and using that key it can encrypt and decrypt message. Now I want to implement key sharing mechnaism.
Which Key-sharing algorithm is the best, and fits in this scenario.
Also please tell me which cryptography is best(asymmetric or symmetric).

Thanks,
Pawan

Answer (score 1):

> I have developed a sample code that does AES-256 Encryption

I hope this will not become production code. I bet your implementations has a ton of side channels allowing for key extraction.

> Which Key-sharing algorithm is the best, and fits in this scenario.

That strongly depends on the application in question.

Comment: It has been taken from an open source code, and I have done changes to it according to my requirement, this needs to be used on Mobile Phone Networks(GSM, GPRS/2G or 3G).

Comment: Did you look at Osmocom already? http://osmocom.org – they might just have what you need.

Comment: thanks for response, But in real scenario, I cannot use any GPL code, thats just for testing purpose right now. Some how I figure out that I need to do symmetric encryption on plain message, and then asymmetric for key sharing and atlast Message Authentican Code(MAC), that is also used in TSL, will that be best idea ?

Comment: This is the typical way. But you'll also need a public key signing method, to avoid man in the middle attacks, and this boils down on a web of trust. Certificate Authorities don't work (this year provided proof).

Comment: Certificate Authorities can certainly work. The current implementation within browsers is however rather lacking. For information between two commercial parties, it is highly recommended to limit the number of allowed CA certificates (e.g. to 1) and use CRL's and OCSP standards. I'm not completely disagreeing with you, but to broadly state that "Certificate Authorities don't work" is a bridge too far.

Comment: @owlstead: On modern OS browsers get their CA root certificates from a central storage. So they will trust _every_ cert in that store, unless it being revoked or hardcoded blacklisted. And they way people use certifacates, making the silliest mistakes.